# icons and alts behaving differently in firefox (font-icons slow to load and displaying alts before page loading)

Tags: javascript, angular, firefox, icons

I have an angular web system. When logging in, in the firefox browser the alts appear before the page loads fully. The icons, on the other hand, have a delay in loading, which causes firefox to display special characters before. Is this a default browser behavior or is there any way around this? I have already tried using ngAfterViewInit and assign variables to the alt attribute (`alt={{var}}`), which start with empty strings and in ngAfterViewInit they get value but still I still have the same problem.

[image]